# How to bind to 'inview' event on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js, inview

I'm playing around with Velocity.js and jquery.inview, and I want all the titles on my page to slideDownIn when they come into view. This code works fine for the first title:

```
$('.movies-title').bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
  if (isInView) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
    if (visiblePartY == 'top') {
      // top part of element is visible
    } else if (visiblePartY == 'bottom') {
      // bottom part of element is visible
    } else {
      // whole part of element is visible
      $(this).velocity("transition.slideDownIn", 500);      
    }
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
    $(this).velocity("reverse");
  }
});
```

If I copy and paste the above several times and replace `.movies-title` with the classes of the other titles, it works as I want it to.

However, that seems like a lot of extra code. I tried  changing `$('.movies-title')` to `$(.movies-title, .tv-title, .books-title)` but then the animation only works for the last element in the list. I also tried adding a new class called `.title` to all of the titles and changing `.movie-title` to `.title` but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong? How can I condense the code?

Comment: A fiddle would be really helpful if you want some more specific help

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/regularmegs/d1g7sLxq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using delegate instead of bind for multiples. Also make a unified class for all of them (I just used title)

so like this -

```
$('body').delegate('.title','inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
```

Edit - sorry linked wrong fiddle initially

see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d1g7sLxq/3/

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Can you explain why your solution works and my original code didn't? What is the difference between delegate and bind?

Comment: No problem! Bind only binds a single event, whereas delegate just adds event listeners.

Comment: @ajmajmajma Wait, why doesn't `.on()` work with this when it works with standard events like `click` on multiple elements just fine. Is this just because of some implementation detail of the `inview` event?

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood Oh interesting! must be because of inview like you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use a single class on each of these elements since they have something so in common. You might just add `title` as a class type and apply it to that class.

```
<div class="title movie-title"></div>
```

I know you mentioned this in your question, but I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I agree ... you should add a class that is the same on all of the objects you want to manipulate, then it is a single jQuery selection.

Comment: It only works on the last element with the class `title`. The other titles above it do not animate.

Comment: Can you post some example code either via jsfiddle or the on-site tool? I can't see what the issue is to help you.